# .NET7 or 8 - WPF - Accessing Windows.Storage throw System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, storage

How do we access Windows.Storage with either .NET7 or 8 and WPF Core packaged for the store?

As an example, we used to do:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "app.log")
            .CreateLogger();
```

However, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path is now throwing:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 
'The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception:
COMException: ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
```

Just for info:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It used to work under Windows 10, and can't seem to find any docs on the topic, is anyone aware?

Comment: What is ApplicationData.LocalFolder supposed to return in a WPF application, which does not reside in an application package in C:\Users\<You>\AppData\Local\Packages\?

Comment: Trying to understand what you say... A StorageFolder, required for msix..

Comment: I mean if you run the application without installation, e.g. from its build directory <YourProject>\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows\. What is LocalFolder then? In a desktop application you would typically use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Comment: Thanks for making my wheels turn Clemens, find the fix, package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility was required..

Comment: Still not clear why you couldn't simply write application data (like log output) as usual, e.g. to Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.

Comment: What you say is surely correct Clemens, but I had so many issues in the past when uploading to the store, that I now always use the UWP / WinUI way.. Correct or not, it does work better for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me after fiddling around, was to install package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility, together with the SDK.Buildtools.

[image]